# how to calculate current system time and store time interval

Tags: java, android, datetime, admob

I want to calculate current system time and store time interval. I am using admob in my application. When a user clicks on ads I want to store current time in `sharedPreferences` and the next ad should show after 10 minutes.

So how i can calculate the interval between time stored in `sharedPreferences` and current system time?

Here is my code.

```
 interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

     @Override
     public void onAdClosed() {
         super.onAdClosed();
         startActivity(intent);
         interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
     }


     @Override
     public void onAdLoaded() {
         // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
         Toast.makeText(Chapters.this, "loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }

     @Override
     public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
         // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.


     }

     @Override
     public void onAdOpened() {
         // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.


     }
     @Override
     public void onAdClicked() {

         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

         // Find todays date
         String currentDateTime = dateFormat.format(new Date()); 
         sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("TimeStamp",MODE_PRIVATE);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
         editor.putString("currenttime",currentDateTime);
         editor.commit();

     }


     @Override
     public void onAdLeftApplication() {
         // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
     }
}
```

Comment: I have rephrased your question substantially to streamline it and make it more intelligible. Please feel free to revert the changes if you think that the current state does not represent what you want to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

> From Question:
>
> When a user clicks on ads I want to store current time in sharedPreferences

Capture the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2019-07-06T04:21:11.091261Z

You may want to [drop the fractional second](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) to zero, for simplicity.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Write this string to storage.

> From Question:
>
> calculate the interval between time stored in sharedPreferences and current system time?

Retrieve that stored string. Parse as a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( instant , Instant.now() ) ;
```

Sanity check.

```
Boolean movingForwardInTime = ( ! d.isNegative() ) && ( ! d.isZero() ) ;
if ( ! movingForwardInTime ) { … }
```

Test if over our limit.

```
Duration limit = Duration.ofMinutes( 10 ) ;
Boolean expired = ( d.compareTo( limit ) > 0 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).